# cypress 10, error on loading typescript file 'You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders'

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, e2e-testing

I just installed cypress 10, e2e test are working normally although I import typescript files, but for component test, I have this error about typescript syntax not being recognized, for example:

```
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ../../node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export type { Something as SomethingElse } from './something';
```

Does not recognize the `export type` on that file.

I followed the UI guide on the cypress GUI, what I find wierd is that e2e test work normally even though I load typescript files but for component test I have this kind of errors

Comment: heard from some devs that switching from CRA to vite solved some of the typescript issues